# Returning Sums of monthly daily averages with current month

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering if it's possible to construct a T-SQL query which returns both total monthly and the daily average sales--including the proper average of the current month.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(7), salesdate, 120) as [Month], 
 SUM(SalesPrice) as [Totals], 
 Max(DAY(EOMONTH(salesdate))), 
 SUM(SalesPrice)/Max(DAY(EOMONTH(salesdate))) 
FROM Sales
WHERE salesdate >= '1/1/2014' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(7), salesdate, 120) 
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Which returns everything fine--except for the current month's daily average, since the formula I'm using to figure out the daily average (sum of the monthly sales/the # of days in that month) is overstating the number of sales days for the current month (unless it's run on the very last day of the month).

Obviously, this could get pieced together as a separate query, but does anyone have the necessary T-SQL mojo to suggest how it might work as a single query?

Comment: That's correct for the current month, but not all the others. Is there a way to CASE this out somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(7), salesdate, 120) as [Month]
     ,SUM(SalesPrice) as [Totals]
     ,Max(DAY(CASE WHEN (MONTH(salesdate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) 
                                     AND (YEAR(salesdate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
                             THEN GETDATE() 
                         ELSE EOMONTH(salesdate) END))
     ,SUM(SalesPrice)/Max(DAY( CASE WHEN (MONTH(salesdate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) 
                                     AND (YEAR(salesdate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
                             THEN GETDATE() 
                         ELSE EOMONTH(salesdate) END)) 
FROM Sales
WHERE salesdate >= '20140101'  --<-- Use ANSI DATE format YYYYMMDD 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(7), salesdate, 120) 
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Comment: Nope it wouldnt work if you were going back more than a Year, and you had multiple years with same months, anyway I have fixed that issue in this edit.

Comment: (Was about to mention that as well, but you beat me to the punch. Thanks again for all your help--didn't know you could CASE inside of functions)